# Can't add MSI.dll to reference in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, windows-installer

I am trying to implement below url.

http://www.alteridem.net/2008/05/20/read-properties-from-an-msi-file/

Whats making me crazy is that I am not able to add Microsoft Windows Installer Object Library using COM components.

Anyone have faced this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is related to my system only and after loads of googling I found that Msi.dll is corrupt. :(

Comment: so how did you fix it???